# ¿Es "qué es lo que" un galicismo? ¿Está aceptado?

Tags: gramática

Recuerdo cuando estudiaba Lenguaje en el colegio que nos enseñaron que "qué es lo que" era un galicismo, proveniente de la construcción francesa "qu'est-ce que", y que se debía evitar. Así:

> ¿Qué es lo que quieres?

debería ser en español sencillamente:

> ¿Qué quieres?

Sin embargo, buscando "qué es lo que" en el CORDE, me salen más de 3300 casos en más de 1200 documentos, lo que indica que es algo muy común en nuestro idioma. Ejemplos (negritas mías):

> *¿**Qué** cosa **es lo que** fue? Aquello mismo que á de venir. ¿**Qué es lo que** es fecho? Aquello que se á de fazer de cabo.*
>
> Alfonso X, "General Estoria. Tercera parte", 1280 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Pero, dejando esto aparte, ¿**qué es lo que** ha de comer vuestra merced en tanto que yo vuelvo?*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha", 1605 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *—Pero eso es absurdo. Yo... Dime **qué es lo que** te ha molestado.*
>
> Carmen Martín Gaite, "Entre visillos", 1958 (España).

En todos estos casos se podría haber simplemente suprimido la parte de "es lo que" y dejar simplemente el "qué" inicial.

¿Qué dice la RAE al respecto? ¿Es realmente un galicismo esta construcción o es propia de nuestro idioma? El hecho de que haya casos tan antiguos me hace dudar de si es un galicismo o si proviene de alguna construcción del latín vulgar. Si es un galicismo, ¿está hoy día aceptado por la RAE o sigue siendo algo a evitar? ¿Existe algún caso en el que el uso de "qué es lo que" no se pueda simplificar como en los ejemplos?

Por otra parte, veo que de los 3300 casos, un 83% son de textos de España. Lo que no sé es si esto indica que en el CORDE la mayoría de textos registrados son de España, o si realmente en Hispanoamérica no se usa tanto esta construcción. ¿Se usa con frecuencia allí?

Comment: @walen tienes razón, de hecho lo pensé durante la redacción de la pregunta. La he modificado para que se refleje esa duda. Y en todo caso, el _citation needed_ es precisamente lo que estoy preguntando...

Answer (score 3):

El [*Diccionario de Galicismos* de Rafael M. Baralt, de 1855](http://biblioteca.org.ar/libros/132480.pdf) [PDF], para la entrada de "ESTO" (pág. 142 del PDF) indica:

> ESTO.- Cuando no sea en la frase española rigurosamente demostrativo, podemos estar seguros de que corresponde al pronombre francés indeclinable *ce*; en cuyo caso es redundante. V. gr.:
>   «¿Qué es esto que veo?» por **¿Qué es lo que veo?**

Nótese que utiliza la construcción "qué es lo que" como ejemplo de lo que sería correcto en español.

Por el contrario, en la entrada de "QUE" (la cual empieza en la página 333 del PDF y ocupa dos páginas y media), no se indica nada al respecto de dicha construcción; a pesar de que, tras leerla, cualquiera diría que TODOS los usos de "que" son galicismos...

Tampoco he encontrado nada sobre tal expresión en otros tratados sobre galicismos que se pueden encontrar *online*.

A la vista de lo anterior, **creo que la expresión "qué es lo que" no es un galicismo**, sino una expresión normal y corriente del español (y por tanto válida).

PD: A lo mejor resulta que es al revés: un españolismo adaptado al francés. Pero, aunque he buscado, no he podido encontrar *corpora* históricos de francés que se puedan consultar gratuitamente para comparar fechas de primeros usos, así que no sabría decirte.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, no sé si esto te ayuda, pero voy a comparar cuándo se usa cada variante en un contexto mexicano, que es lo que mejor conozco.  Quizás esto quedaría mejor como comentario, pero el formato de respuesta me queda mejor.

**Escenario 1**. Un familiar me interrumpe cuando estoy por ejemplo en el teléfono, pero luego tarda en decirme de qué se trata.  Para ayudarle a llegar al grano, digo

> ¿Qué quieres?

O si es mi suegra, que se crió en el campo,

> ¿Qué quiere Ud.?

Esto implica un poco de impaciencia.  Lo puedo suavizar así:

> ¿Qué querías? / ¿Qué quería Ud.?

**Escenario 2**. Voy a ir al supermercado.  Estoy preparando mi lista.  Pregunto a cada familiar

> ¿Qué quieres tú [del súper], Fulano?

**Escenario 3**.  Una amiga me está contando algo de su hijo.  Expresa sus frustraciones, todo mezclado, con ciertas contradicciones.  Para ayudarla a identificar sus principales prioridades, le pregunto

> ¿Qué es lo que quieres?

**Escenario 4**.  La misma amiga me cuenta que su hijo aceptó una invitación del papá (que no vive con ellos), a pesar de que no la pasó bien las otras veces que visitó a su papá.  Le digo

> ¿Qué quieres?  Es natural que siga buscando al papá de sus fantasías.

En un contexto formal, "Qué" se podría oir un poco seco.  "¿Qué quieres?", de un profesor universitario, por ejemplo, no se oiría nada bien.  Y en una tienda, van a usar una formulación alternativa que expresa más cortesía, por ejemplo

> ¿Qué se le ofrece?

¿Los diálogos serían diferentes en tu región?

Comment: No estoy seguro de entender adónde quieres llegar con tu argumentación. Entiendo que quieres decir que "qué es lo que quieres" es una pregunta que suena más suave que decir "qué quieres", y que por tanto no se puede cambiar la una por la otra porque cada una se usa en un contexto diferente. ¿Es así?

Comment: @Charlie - Um, creo que sí, as así.  Te doy situaciones donde "qué quieres" me suena más natural que "qué es lo que quieres".  Luego tú podrás decir cómo es la cosa en tu región -- yo no puedo hacer esa comparación.

Comment: Pero acabo de ver tu rollback y ahora creo que entendí mal la pregunta.

Comment: Siento el rollback, pero es que la pregunta no va de esta expresión en Hispanoamérica, eso es solo una pequeña pregunta extra. Lo principal es saber si la expresión es o no es un galicismo, y si lo es, saber si se considera correcta o incorrecta.

Comment: No hay problema, es tu pregunta.  Me fijé en "si realmente en Hispanoamérica no se usa tanto esta construcción" y no capté que eso era muy secundario. // De todas maneras, ¿qué me dices de mis escenarios?  ¿En cuáles usarías "Qué es lo que"?

Answer (score 0):

No es exactamente la frase en la pregunta pero siento que el caso es similar y sigue un mismo patrón (bajo el riesgo de que sea un uso regional). Se trata de "¿cuál es?" y "¿cuál es que es?". Se podría pensar que la parte de "es que" se podría obviar, pero en el uso que yo he visto, las frases tienen una sutil diferencia.

Supongamos que nos presentan al alguien en una fiesta y al cabo de unos minutos hemos olvidado su nombre. Dos opciones para preguntar por el nombre podrían ser:

> ¿Cuál es tu nombre?

Esta opción es gramaticalmente correcta, pero seguramente el interlocutor va a poner una cara rara porque ya nos dijo su nombre.

> ¿Cuál es que es tu nombre?

Con esta frase se da la idea de que la información por la que preguntamos no es completamente nueva y que más bien estamos pidiendo una "confirmación" de algo que en teoría ya sabemos. Lo veo como una forma ambigua y sutil que no especifica si es que olvidamos por completo el nombre o si no estamos seguros de haberlo escuchado bien (¿era Paola o Paula?). Esto de alguna manera nos ahorra lo incómodo que podría ser en algunos casos admitir que hemos olvidado el nombre.

De esta manera, el "es que" bien podría ser uno de los equivalentes de la fórmula en inglés "again" para confirmar información:

> [*"Sorry, what was your name again?"*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3257)
>
> Disculpa, ¿cuál es que es tu nombre?

Otro posible matiz que da el uso de "es [lo] que" es un poco de dramatismo, en mi punto de vista. La oración:

> En fin, alma de Satanás, ¿qué es lo que quieres? <sub>[1](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll)</sub>

no tendría la misma fuerza o sentimiento de desespero o impaciencia si simplemente se escribiera:

> En fin, alma de Satanás, ¿qué quieres?